# Nodejs Custom sort behaves differently in node12 compared to node10

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running my code in AWS Lambda(Nodejs). have below code to sort my custom array of objects

```
let a = [];
let ob1= {"ts": "1582709708.009700"};
let ob2= {"ts": "1582709806.011000"};
let ob3= {"ts": "1582709782.010600"};
let ob4= {"ts": "1582709777.010400"};
let ob5= {"ts": "1582709791.010800"};
a.push(ob1);
a.push(ob2);
a.push(ob3);
a.push(ob4);
a.push(ob5);

a.sort((m1, m2) => {
          let m1Ts = moment.unix(m1.ts).utc();
          let m2Ts = moment.unix(m2.ts).utc();
          return m1Ts.isAfter(m2Ts);
      });
```

the above code returns below result with a runtime of 12.x

> [{"ts":"1582709708.009700"},{"ts":"1582709806.011000"},{"ts":"1582709782.010600"},{"ts":"1582709777.010400"},{"ts":"1582709791.010800"}]

and for a runtime of 10.x

> [{"ts":"1582709708.009700"},{"ts":"1582709777.010400"},{"ts":"1582709782.010600"},{"ts":"1582709791.010800"},{"ts":"1582709806.011000"}]

The same code gives different results for the sort. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your comparator function should [return a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), not a boolean. Have you tried [`return m1Ts - m2Ts`](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1493#issuecomment-35960403)?

Comment: I tried with this: if(m1Ts.isAfter(m2Ts)){return 1} with other conditions for -1 and 0 added. but same result

Comment: @rayhatfield changing it to m1Ts-m2Ts seems to have solved the issue. Any idea why?

Comment: When given a comparator function, `Array.sort` determines order on the basis of whether the function returns a value greater than, equal to, or less than zero. You can subtract one moment instance from another to get the timestamp difference, which will be greater than zero, zero, or less than zero according to whether `m1Ts` is after `m2Ts`, equal to it, or before it respectively. So simply subtracting one from the other produces a suitable sort value.

Comment: Understood. but why does it behave differently in node10 and node12?

Comment: Don't know. Close examination of [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort) or [node's src](https://github.com/nodejs/node) might illuminate it if you really want to get into it. I suspect it's just an implementation detail that changed the behavior when the comparator returns a boolean instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the algorithm has  been changed to Timsort after nodejs11. The order of arguments passed to compare function is changed. You can look into this :https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24294